# Prove this induction problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Show that every positive integer $N$ less than or equal to $n$ factorial, is the sum of at most $n$ distinct positive integers, each of which divides $n!$.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi. I am really stuck on this problem.

Comment: I have tried picking numbers and I have tried to see a pattern but haven't got anywhere yet.

Comment: Do you understand how an induction proof works?  What is the first step?  What assumption can you make based on the first step?  What do you do with that assumption?

Comment: Yes, you have to prove P(n) is true and then you can prove P(n+1) is true.

Comment: Actually, you prove $P(1)$ is true, which allows you to assume there is a positive number $n$ such that $P(n)$ is true.  Once you have done that, you prove $P(n + 1)$ is true based on your assumption that $P(n)$ is true or your assumption that $P(m)$ holds for each each integer $m \leq n$.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I am not seeing a pattern or anything. Will you please help me?

Comment: I am thinking about the $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + 1)$ step.

Comment: Another possible edit: remove `!` at the end, it confuses between exclamation and factorial

Comment: ok. It is supposed to be factorial though.

Comment: Do you understand why $P(1)$ holds?

Comment: no, sorry. I actually didn't even know how to start this one cause it's a little different than the others.

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: $P(1)$ is the statement that every positive integer $N \leq 1!$ is the sum of at most $1$ positive integers each of which divides $1!$.  It holds because $1! = 1$ is the sum of one positive integer, namely $1$.  Since that is true, you may assume there exists a positive $m$ such that $P(m)$ is true.  At this point, I am still thinking about the $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m + 1)$ step, which appears to be tricky.

Comment: ok I appreciate your help so far. Is there a need to derive a formula for this in the first part? Also when you say P(m) do you mean P(n+1)?

Comment: are you still there?

Answer (score 3):

We deal with the induction step. Suppose that the result holds when $n=k$. We show the result holds when $n=k+1$. So we want to show that every positive integer $N\le (k+1)!$ is representable as a sum $y_1+\cdots +y_t$, where $t\le k+1$, and where the $y_j$ are distinct divisors of $(k+1)!$.

If $N$ is divisible by $k+1$, we are essentially finished. For we have $\frac{N}{k+1}\le k!$. Thus,  using the induction hypothesis, we can represent $\frac{N}{k+1}$ as $\frac{N}{k+1}=x_1+\cdots +x_t$, where $t\le k$ and the $x_j$ are distinct divisors of $k!$. Let $y_j=(k+1)x_j$. Then $N=y_1+\cdots +y_t$, and the $y_j$ are distinct divisors of $(k+1)!$.

Now suppose that $N$ is not divisible by $k+1$. Then $N$ leaves some remainder $r$ on division by $k+1$, where $1\le r\le k$.

Then $N-r$ is divisible by $n+1$.  So again by the induction hypothesis there exists a $s\le k$, and distinct divisors $x_1,\dots, x_s$ of $k!$, such that
$\frac{N-r}{k+1}=x_1+\cdots +x_s$.

Let $y_j=(k+1)x_j$ for $1\le j\le s$, and let $y_{s+1}=r$. Then $s+1\le k+1$, and $N=y_1+\cdots+y_s+y_{s+1}$.

For $1\le j\le s$,  the $x_j$ are distinct divisors of $k!$.  Thus the $y_j$ are distinct divisors of $(k+1)!$. Since $y_{s+1}=r\le k$, it follows that $y_{s+1}$ is also a divisor of $(k+1)!$. Finally, $y_{s+1}$ is not equal to any $y_j$ with $j\le s$, since $y_{s+1}$ is not divisible by $k+1$, but the others are.

This completes the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Show that the statement holds for $n=1$.  For this value of $n$ we have $1!=1$, and thus every positive integer less than or equal to $1!$ is the set $\{1\}$.  Since $n=1$ we must find a sum of at most one positive integer which divides $1!$ and adds up to each of the numbers in our given set, and indeed we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^11=1$$

This proves the case for $n=1$.

The second step is to assume that the proposition is true for $n=k\ge 1$.  We now adopt this assumption, namely that every positive integer less than or equal to $n!=k!\ge 1!$ is the sum of at most $n=k$ distinct positive integers, each of which divides $n!=k!$.

The last step is to prove that this assumption leads to the conclusion that the proposition holds for the case $n=k+1$.  One way to start is to take a number which is considered "arbitrary" from the range associated with this case; another approach would be to do a secondary induction over the set of numbers associated with this case.

Comment: What would be the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: The secondary induction hypothesis would involve only the numbers from $n!+1$ to $(n+1)!$, but it looks like there is another better answer already.

Comment: yeah thanks though!

Comment: abiessu, the answer Andre gave above. Do I need to show both cases where N is divisible by n+1 and N is not divisible by n+1? Or is just necessary for me to show N is divisible by n+1.